# Append div in button on click Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi how to append div inside button on click this is my JavaScript:

```
function addLoader() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="loader"> <div class="loader-ring"> <div class="loader-ring-light"></div> </div> </div>';
    var test01 = document.createElement('button');
    test01.appendChild(div);
    console.log(test01);
}
```

I want to add innerHTML inside button tags on click

```
<button onclick="addLoader(this);">testt </button>
```

It must be like this when function is finish :

```
<button>testt <div class="loader"> <div class="loader-ring"> <div class="loader-ring-light"></div> </div> </div> </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
// Added id attribute
<button onclick="addLoader();" id = "test01">testt </button>
```

**JS**

```
function addLoader() {
    var _div = document.createElement('div');
    _div.innerHTML = '<div class="loader"> <div class="loader-ring"> <div class="loader-ring-light"></div> </div> </div>';
    //append _div to button
    document.getElementById("test01").appendChild(_div);

}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vo6gjvt/)

[image: Snapshot]
**EDIT**

This will append element to any button call  `addLoader` on click

```
function addLoader(elem) {
        var _div = document.createElement('div');
        _div.innerHTML = '<div class="loader"> <div class="loader-ring"> <div class="loader-ring-light"></div> </div> </div>';
        elem.appendChild(_div);
    }
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vo6gjvt/1/)

Comment: Can I do this without using any ID class? just button tag?

Comment: You can do that but it will be complex, reason is there can be multiple button in your page. Do you want to add same DOM element inside other button also?

Comment: Yes but jos on buttons that have onclick function

Comment: @EdinPuzic updated the answer.Please check updated jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("addLoader");

if (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', addLoader, false);
}

function addLoader() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<div class="loader"> <div class="loader-ring"> <div class="loader-ring-light"></div> </div> </div>';
  this.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<button id="addLoader">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one more line of code. The variable `test01` is created in memory but not added to the `DOM`.  You must append this new element to the DOM (ie. `document.appendChild(test01)`)