# How to spawn a tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to  click on button to add  with this css styles:

```
.olusturucu select {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 210px;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
  background: #2e303b;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

[image: dkfkh]

Is this possible if its can you help me?

Comment: Add the element to the DOM, and use `class="olusturucu"` in the element.

Comment: This solution should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892221/3174790

Answer (score 0):

This should work based on what I think you're trying to do (append a select element to a .olusturucu element):

```
 var element = document.createElement("select") //create "select" element
 element.innerHTML = "foo bar baz"; //add text
 document.findElementsByClassName("olusturucu")[0].appendChild(element); // find the first .olusturucu element, and append the element to it
```

Answer (score 0):

The following little function will toggle a class by another one, selecting an element by id. Very useful for your use case.

```js
function toggleClass(id,classA,classB){
  if (document.getElementById(id).classList[0] === classA){
    document.getElementById(id).classList = classB
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).classList = classA
 }
}

button.onclick = () => toggleClass("elem1" , "red", "chartreuse")
```

```css
.red {
  background:red
}

.chartreuse {
  background:chartreuse
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1" class="red">Some stuffs</div>

<button id="button">Toggle class</button>
```